# SQL Server - Split column data and retrieve last second value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have a column name **MasterCode** in XYZ Table where data is stored in below form.

```
.105248.105250.104150.111004.
```

Now first of all I want to split the data into :

```
105248
105250
104150
111004
```

Then after to retrieve only last second value from the above.

So In the above given array, value returned should be `104150`.

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: server version??

Comment: SQL Server 2017.

Comment: use string_split()

Comment: I have tried that. But its not working.

Comment: what output you get?

Comment: select * from STRING_SPLIT('.105248.105250.104150.111004.', '.')

Comment: Error : Invalid object name 'STRING_SPLIT'.

Comment: You must not be using SQL Server 2017 then. Maybe you're using Management Studio 2017 but connecting to an older version of SQL Server. What does `SELECT @@VERSION;` return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a split string function, but not the built in once since it will return only the values and you will lose the location data.

You can use Jeff Moden's [`DelimitedSplit8K`](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) that will return the item and the item index:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K]
--===== Define I/O parameters
        (@pString VARCHAR(8000), @pDelimiter CHAR(1))
--WARNING!!! DO NOT USE MAX DATA-TYPES HERE!  IT WILL KILL PERFORMANCE!
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
 RETURN
--===== "Inline" CTE Driven "Tally Table" produces values from 1 up to 10,000...
     -- enough to cover VARCHAR(8000)
  WITH E1(N) AS (
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
                ),                          --10E+1 or 10 rows
       E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
       E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
 cteTally(N) AS (--==== This provides the "base" CTE and limits the number of rows right up front
                     -- for both a performance gain and prevention of accidental "overruns"
                 SELECT TOP (ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@pString),0)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
                ),
cteStart(N1) AS (--==== This returns N+1 (starting position of each "element" just once for each delimiter)
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT t.N+1 FROM cteTally t WHERE SUBSTRING(@pString,t.N,1) = @pDelimiter
                ),
cteLen(N1,L1) AS(--==== Return start and length (for use in substring)
                 SELECT s.N1,
                        ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@pDelimiter,@pString,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000)
                   FROM cteStart s
                )
--===== Do the actual split. The ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the length for the final element when no delimiter is found.
 SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY l.N1),
        Item       = SUBSTRING(@pString, l.N1, l.L1)
   FROM cteLen l
;
```

Then you can use it to split the string and it will return a table like this:

```
DECLARE @string varchar(100) = '.105248.105250.104150.111004.';

SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K](@string, '.')

ItemNumber  Item
1   
2           105248
3           105250
4           104150
5           111004
6
```

You want only the parts where there actually is an item, so add a where clause, and you want the second from last so add `row_number()`, and you want the entire thing in a common table expression so that you can query it:

```
DECLARE @string varchar(100) = '.105248.105250.104150.111004.';

WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT Item, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ItemNumber DESC) As rn
    FROM [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K](@string, '.')
    WHERE Item <> ''
)
```

And the query:

```
SELECT Item
FROM CTE
WHERE rn = 2
```

Result: `104150`

Comment: It works! Thank you for taking time to solve the problem.

Comment: [Glad to help :-)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291325/how-to-show-appreciation-to-a-user-on-stackoverflow/291327#291327)

Answer (score 2):

If there are always four parts, you can use `PARSENAME()`:

```
DECLARE @s varchar(64) = '.105248.105250.104150.111004.';

SELECT PARSENAME(SUBSTRING(@s, 2, LEN(@s)-2),2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your version of SQL SERVER, you can also use the `STRING_SPLIT` function.

```
DECLARE @string varchar(100) = '.105248.105250.104150.111004.';

SELECT  value,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CHARINDEX('.' + value + '.', '.' + @string + '.')) AS Pos
FROM    STRING_SPLIT(@string,'.')  
WHERE   RTRIM(value) <> '';
```

It doesn't return the original position like Jeff's splitter, but does compare very favourably if you check Aaron Bertrand's Article :

[Performance Surprises and Assumptions : STRING_SPLIT()](https://sqlperformance.com/2016/03/sql-server-2016/string-split)

*Edit*:

*Added position, but although works in this case may have issues with duplicate values*

Comment: Yes, but without the preservation of the order, it's useless in this (and many other) cases...

Comment: True, I knew it didn't return the ordinal position, but wasn't aware that the function does not specify the split order so cannot be guaranteed. I have updated the answer

Comment: I think the OP is mistaken about their version of SQL Server, but @ZoharPeled for more info about ordering and duplicates with `STRING_SPLIT()` see [STRING_SPLIT and ordered results](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/207293/1186) and [Solve old problems with SQL Server’s new STRING_AGG and STRING_SPLIT functions](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5275/solve-old-problems-with-sql-servers-new-stringagg-and-stringsplit-functions/). It is definitely not useless especially when you consider the performance delta.

Comment: @Aaron That's a nice trick, and sure makes the use if `string_split` worth considering, but the duplicates in data might be a problem as you wrote. Anyway, good to know.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a SQL server table valued function with parameters stringvalue and delemeter and call that function for the results as expected.

```
ALTER function [dbo].[SplitString] 
(
@str nvarchar(4000), 
@separator char(1)
)
returns table
AS
return (
with tokens(p, a, b) AS (
select 
1, 
1, 
charindex(@separator, @str)
union all
select
p + 1, 
b + 1, 
charindex(@separator, @str, b + 1)
from tokens
where b > 0
)
select
p-1 ID,
substring(
@str, 
a, 
case when b > 0 then b-a ELSE 4000 end) 
AS s
from tokens
)
```

To call the function

```
SELECT * FROM [DBO].[SPLITSTRING] ('.105248.105250.104150.111004.', '.') WHERE ISNULL(S,'') <> ''
```

Output

```
ID  s
1   105248
2   105250
3   104150
4   111004
```

To get only second value you can write your query as shown below

```
DECLARE @MaxID INT
SELECT @MaxID = MAX (ID) FROM (SELECT * FROM [DBO].[SPLITSTRING] ('.105248.105250.104150.111004.', '.') WHERE ISNULL(S,'') <> '') A

SELECT TOP 1 @MaxID =  MAX (ID) FROM (
SELECT * FROM [DBO].[SPLITSTRING] ('.105248.105250.104150.111004.', '.') WHERE ISNULL(S,'') <> ''
)a where ID < @MaxID

SELECT * FROM [DBO].[SPLITSTRING] ('.105248.105250.104150.111004.', '.') WHERE ISNULL(S,'') <> '' AND ID = @MaxID
```

Output

```
ID  s
3   104150
```

If you want 1 as value of ID then you can write your query as shown below in last line of query.

```
SELECT 1 AS ID , S FROM [DBO].[SPLITSTRING] ('.105248.105250.104150.111004.', '.') WHERE ISNULL(S,'') <> '' AND ID = @MaxID
```

Then the output will be

```
ID  S
1   104150
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DECLARE @DATA AS TABLE (Data nvarchar(1000))
INSERT INTO @DATA
SELECT '.105248.105250.104150.111004.'
;WITH CTE
AS
(
SELECT Data,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY Data DESC) AS Rnk
FROM
(
    SELECT Split.a.value('.','nvarchar(100)') Data
    FROM(
    SELECT CAST('<S>'+REPLACE(Data,'.','</S><S>')+'</S>' AS XML ) As Data
    FROM @DATA
)DT 
CROSS APPLY Data.nodes('S') AS Split(a)
) AS Fnl
WHERE Fnl.Data <>''

)
SELECT Data FROM CTE
WHERE Rnk=2
```

Result

```
Data
-----
105248
105250
104150
111004
```

Answer (score 0):

It can also be achieve only using string functions:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #temp

SELECT '.105248.105250.104150.111004.' code INTO #temp UNION ALL 
SELECT '.205248.205250.204150.211004.' 

SELECT 
REVERSE(LEFT(
            REVERSE(LEFT(code,  LEN(code) - CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(code), 2)))
            ,  CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(LEFT(code,  LEN(code) - CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(code), 2)))) -1
            )
        )   second_last_value
FROM #temp
```

Result:

```
second_last_value
-----------------------------
104150
204150
```